# Edit order from backend

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Is it possible to add products and discounts to an order from backend?
From what I see it's only possible to edit the orders custom fields.

Answer (score 3):

Currently no, however the ability to edit completed order details is on the list for 1.1.

Comment: @Spoeken Craft Commerce 1.1 now supports adding payments to an order on the backend. You can also mark a cart as a completed order, as well as updating the order’s addresses.

Comment: @brandon-kelly Will it be possible to edit a line item variant from the backend?